Is there a way to trigger DAG when the current run fails?
Can I trigger a DAG immediately when the current run fails (it doesn't matter which of the tasks failed), without scheduling it?

You can configure retries to some count , whenever any task fails system will retry the specific task to that count.
Sample code as below:
default_args = {
'retries': 3,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}
dag = DAG('my_dag', default_args=default_args)

I dont want to retry the task, i want to retry the entire dag - the whole flow from the beginning

I have never tried this, but I have an idea may be you can try this. 1. Define a method to clear the start task of the dag programatically. 2.Add this method to on_failure_callback
